# How to keep local component data , e.g. spinners/errors, outside of Flux stores?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, refluxjs

**Note:** I am using Reflux as my Flux library, so the samples will use its syntax. The question applies to Flux in general, however.

In my sample Flux application I have a `productStore.js` file that holds the state of the products in the system and listens to various product management actions, e.g `REMOVE_PRODUCT`, `ADD_PRODUCT`.

Here is a sample data in the store:

```
{
    products: [
        {
            productName: "A"
        },
        {
            productName: "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to add a `REFRESH_PRODUCTS` action to a component.

The invocation looks like that:

**component.jsx**

```
onRefresh(e) {
    actions.refreshProducts();
}
```

Since refreshing the products is an async operation, I would like to show the spinner while it goes on and show an error if it fails. The obvious, Flux way, would be to add the loading state and the resulting error, if such happens, to the store, like so:

**productStore.js**

```
onRefreshProducts() {

    logger.info("Logging in:", email);
    this.storeData.inProgress = true;
    this.storeData.error = null;
    this.trigger(this.data);

    api.getProducts()
        .then((response) => {
            this.storeData.products = response.data.products;
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            this.storeData.error = error;
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.storeData.inProgress = false;
            this.trigger(this.data);
        });
}
```

And now the store of the data becomes dirty with various flags:

```
{
    inProgress: false,
    error: null,

    products: [
        {
            productName: "A"
        },
        {
            productName: "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

This kind of state would be perfectly fine for me if multiple components would need to see the progress of products loading, or refresh failing, but in case, no other components needs that kind of information. So it feels I am putting private data to global state without a good reason.

I would like to be able to do something like that:

**component.jsx - BAD CODE**

```
onRefresh(e) {

    this.setState({error: false, inProgress: true});
    actions.refreshProducts()
        .catch(function(err) {
            this.setState({error: err});
        })
        .then(function() {
            this.setState({inProgress: false});
        });
}
```

Then I could keep the code of store clean. However, I have no obvious way to do that - Actions, by design, create a separation that don't allow to return data from actions.

What's the proper way to do it? How can I do private spinners/errors/etc while keeping the related data out of global state?

Comment: Why not just set it on the state of the component, rather than in the store? Use setState({}), like you normally would. If I am understanding your question correctly - for pagewide states, I use the store - for component specific state, I just store it in there.

Comment: Because the product data **should** be in the store. So I do want to update the store. I just want to keep the progress/error handling of the process inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution I thought of while writing this question:

- Create a new action on the store that allows to update the product data by argument, e.g: `refreshProductFromData`
- Call the API directly from the component
- Manipulate the spinners/error handling in the component
- Pass the data retrieved from API to the store via the new action

Like so:

**component.jsx**

```
onRefresh(e) {

    this.setState({error: false, inProgress: true});
    api.getProducts()
        .then(function(data) {
            actions.refreshProductFromData(response.data.products);
        });
        .catch(function(err) {
            this.setState({error: err});
        })
        .then(function() {
            this.setState({inProgress: false});
        });
}
```

Not sure if it is the right/best solution or not however.

Answer (score 0):

I found your post because I had the same question.  I think I'm going to structure mine like this, keeping everything decoupled and communicating via actions.  I like to keep the component and store ignorant with regards to the API.

- The Product Actions know how to interact with the API to complete the requested action.
- The Product Store listens to the Completed action to update its internal state.
- The LoadingActions manage the spinner state and are asked to show/hide the spinner when API calls are initiated.
- I have a Spinner component that listens to LoadingActions and updates its state to show/hide the spinner.

Component:

```
actions.refresh();
```

(Product) Actions:

```
onRefresh: function () {
    LoadingActions.showSpinner();
    api.loadProducts().then(this.completed, this.failed).finally(LoadingActions.hideSpinner);
}
```

Loading Actions:

```
onShowSpinner: function () { ... }
onHideSpinner: function () { ... }
```

Store:

```
onRefreshCompleted: function (data) {
    this.products = data;
    this.trigger();
}
```